# Sphinx autodocumentation of function calls

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pseudocode, autodoc

I would like to be able to pull docstrings and/or comments from the body of a method into the main docstring for the method.

That is to say something along the lines of

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
     """This is a summary of the initialization which does the following:
     """

     my_list = []
     """ a list to hold things """

     self.setup_stuff()
     """ sets up stuff"""

     self.initialize_stuff()
     """ initializes stuff"""
```

I know that

```
.. autoclass:: MyClass
   :members:
```

will produce documentation for the doc string from __ init __ and for my_list.

It would be nice if sphinx could somehow append the strings under 'setup_stuff' and 'initialize_stuff'. That way you could make naturally styled comments in your code and have the documentation produce a kind of psuedocode from it.

Comment: Public documentation (as generated by Sphinx) should document the interfaces (packages, modules, classes, methods, parameters, ...) but not the implementation (code, variables, ...). Only the first string after a declaration is considered a docstring, all other "docstrings" are just unassigned values.

Comment: How about letting users see actual code instead of pseudocode? [sphinx.ext.viewcode](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/viewcode.html)

Comment: @Paebbels perhaps I need to be looking for an other documentation tool? My goal is to hand off my project to the next generation of developer, and have the maximum amount of this documentation live as close to the code as possible.

Comment: @mzjn The problem is that I am trying to document a messy code-base. The future developers will be looking at the code, but it would be nice if the code could generate a skeleton of itself by collecting comments rather than having the next developer pour over and have to parse each statement.

Comment: Note also that what I am trying to document is a sort of in-house framework the users of which develop their own projects by overloading and re-implementing parts in their own project, therefore it is important to be able to clearly relate what modules do inside their __init__ methods to other developers

Comment: No not really, because single instructions in a function shouldn't be documented, otherwise you should reconsider refactoring e.g. into more functions with less complexity and naming such functions so a user can understand their functionality by function name. Creating more functions also means more (private) API documentation. Comments should be used to document blocks of instructions, not docstrings.

Comment: @Paebbels 'you should reconsider refactoring e.g. into more functions with less complexity and naming such functions so a user can understand their functionality by function name. ' This is precisely what I was doing and I wanted a way to easily add all of these tasks to the __init__ function.

Comment: OK. That sounds good. Then describe all the steps, which are performed in the init method in the docstring of init. You can use ReStructured Text markup e.g. to created lists or ordered lists.